# Why the input show the half text while ajax response having full string

Tags: jquery

I have an script which fetching the data from the apis and in ajax success response ajax got:-

```
date: "2018-12-06"
date_time: 1544077867
description: "This is second image"
id: 2
image_url: "image_url/image.jpg"
name: "Second Image"
status: 1
```

While append the data with input field then it will show for example from above data it show the `description like "This"` while `description having "This is a second image"`. This same thing also done with the `name` to it will show in input field is "Second" while it contains "Second Image". I posted my code below:-

```
success:function(response){
  console.log(response.response.data)
  console.log(response.response.data.description)
  $('#elements').append('<input id="name" type="text" value='+response.response.data.name+'><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="description" type="text" value='+response.response.data.description+'><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="image_url" type="text" value='+response.response.data.image_url+'><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="date" type="text" value='+response.response.data.date+'><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="date" type="hidden" value='+response.response.data.id+'><br><br>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your result stirngs into quotes:

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="'+response.response.data.name+'">
                                   ^                               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Change `value='+response.response.data.name+'` to `"'+response.response.data.name+'"`

```js
var response={
  response:{
    data:{
    date: "2018-12-06",
    date_time: 1544077867,
    description: "This is second image",
    id: 2,
    image_url: "image_url/image.jpg",
    name: "Second Image",
    status: 1
    }
  }
}
 $('#elements').append('<input id="name" type="text" value="'+response.response.data.name+'"><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="description" type="text" value="'+response.response.data.description+'"><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="image_url" type="text" value="'+response.response.data.image_url+'"><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="date" type="text" value="'+response.response.data.date+'"><br><br>');
  $('#elements').append('<input id="date" type="hidden" value="'+response.response.data.id+'"><br><br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">

</div>
```